# How to insert values based on another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is a subset of my table (for the first id)

| date | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 1 | 5 |
| 08/01/2022 | 1 | 2 |

For each id, the dates are not consecutive (e.g., for id 1, the min date is 01/01/2022 and the max date is 08/01/2022)--there are 7 days in between both dates. I want to insert rows to make the dates for each id consecutive and contiguous - the value for the value field/column to be filled with 0s so that the updated table looks like:

| date | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 1 | 5 |
| 02/01/2022 | 1 | 0 |
| 03/01/2022 | 1 | 0 |
| 04/01/2022 | 1 | 0 |
| 05/01/2022 | 1 | 0 |
| 06/01/2022 | 1 | 0 |
| 07/01/2022 | 1 | 0 |
| 08/01/2022 | 1 | 2 |

Any SQL code on how to implement this would be highly appreciated. I have a calendar table but am unsure how to join it with the above table so that I fill in missing dates dynamically for each id with 0s.

My calendar table looks like:

| date |
| --- |
| 01/01/2022 |
| 02/01/2022 |
| 03/01/2022 |
| 04/01/2022 |

Comment: A Calendar table appears to be what you need here.

Comment: Thank you provided that I have a Calendar table, please could you provide the code to implement my requirement? Thanks @Larnu

Comment: @Larnu I have a calendar table but am unsure how to join in with the above table so that I fill in missing dates dynamically for each id with 0s based on the min and max date for each id. Many thanks.

Comment: If you already have a calendar table, share what you've tried and add both the table and your attempt to this post.

Comment: @lemon i have added in the Calendar in my recent edit. As for my attempt, I am unsure as to where to start since my table has many ids with differing min and max dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you state you have a calendar table, it seems what you need to do with `JOIN` to it with the `MIN` and `MAX` dates from your other table, and the `LEFT JOIN` back to your table:

```sql
WITH MinMax AS(
    SELECT ID,
           MIN(date) AS MinDate,
           MAX(date) AS MaxDate
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    GROUP BY ID),
Dates AS(
    SELECT MM.ID,
           C.CalendarDate AS [Date]
    FROM MinMax MM
         JOIN dbo.CalendarTable C ON MM.MinDate <= C.CalendarDate
                                 AND MM.MaxDate >= C.CalendarDate)
SELECT D.ID,
       D.[Date],
       ISNULL(YT.[Value],0) AS [Value]
FROM Dates D
     LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON D.ID = YT.ID
                               AND D.[Date] = YT.[Date];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY

-- CREATE A TABLE WITH OUR INPUT DATA
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TheData
GO
CREATE TABLE #TheData
(TheDate DATE, id INT, TheValue INT)
INSERT INTO #TheData
(TheDate,id,Thevalue)
VALUES
('01/01/2022',1,5),
('08/01/2022',1,2),
('17/01/2022',2,7),
('25/01/2022',2,7),
('15/02/2022',2,7)

-- CREATE A CALENDAR CTE

DECLARE @StartDate  date = '20210101';
DECLARE @CutoffDate date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR, 2, @StartDate));

;WITH DateSeq(TheDate) AS 
(
  SELECT @StartDate 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT DATEADD(dd,1,TheDate) FROM DateSeq
  WHERE TheDate < @CutoffDate
)

-- CROSS JOIN OUR CALENDAR CTE TO OUR SOURCE DATA. DERIVED TABLE TO GET FIRST AND LAST OF EACH RANGE TO USE FOR JOIN
SELECT
ds.*
,SourceDataRangesByID.ID
,ISNULL(td.TheValue,0) AS TheValue
FROM
DateSeq ds
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 
    d.ID
    ,MIN(d.TheDate) AS MinDatePerID
    ,MAX(d.TheDate) AS MaxDatePerID
    FROM #TheData d 
    GROUP BY d.ID
) SourceDataRangesByID 
LEFT JOIN #TheData td ON td.id = SourceDataRangesByID.ID AND td.TheDate = ds.TheDate
WHERE ds.TheDate >= SourceDataRangesByID.MinDatePerID
AND ds.TheDate <= SourceDataRangesByID.MaxDatePerID

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

try the generate_series to create a date table then right join with it and coalesce for the non null value

```
SELECT generate_series('2016-01-01',  -- series start date
                           '2018-06-30',  -- series end date
                           '1 day'::interval)::date AS day) AS daily_series
   from mytable

See Generate_Series for TSQL

 https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/255165/does-ms-sql-server-have-generate-series-function 

(Sql server 2022)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
```